# python onehotencoding or labelencoding for category variable with 2 levels?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data

I am working on binary classification problem using ML where my data has a feature with just 2 levels where one level has more importance than another. It is not pure categorical (this is not exactly like gender). Will onehotencoder for just 2 levels make so much difference compared to mere LabelEncoder in this case?
In what scenarios do we use onehotencoding/ labelencoding?

Comment: Add more details to your question. What you are trying to do? which programming language you are using?

Comment: Im using python for binary classification problem. I have some categorical features in my data and some of those have only 2 levels.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what machine learning algorithm you are going to use on your data.

What is your final goal? Is it classification? Is it clustering?

If it is classification then using certain kinds of classifiers will only make sense if you have one hot encoded labels.

In general it is better for classification if you one-hot-encode your categorical features.